problem about line passing through the orthocenter and midpoint of the arc containing A
I'm doing a geometric problem and there's only one last step left to complete, which is to prove this problem, but I really can't think of anything, it's essentially equivalent to proving PCA=BAC/2, (I will edit and post the problem I am working on once the solution is complete)
Let triangle ABC be inscribed in the circle with center O. H is the orthocenter of the triangle, M is the midpoint of arc BC containing A. The line through O parallel to AM intersects HM at P. Prove that B,C,O ,P belongs to the same circle
pls, help and thank you so much

original problem, PM, PN, PV are perpendicular to BC, CA, AB, prove that midpoint of HM belong to (MNV).
i call S is midpoint of HM, HJ parallel to AM (J belong to OM). JX,JY,JZ are perpendicular to BC, CA, AB. if i have OPBC is a cyclic quadrilatera, i can prove that PCH=OCJ,BPH=OBJ (Just a simple change)
so X,Y,Z belong to (HMV). i have AMJH is a parallelogram so S is midpoint of AJ
so ZSY=ZSJ+YSJ=2ZAJ+2YAJ=2BAC, another face: ZXY=JXZ+JXY=JBX+JCX=2JBX=2(90-XJC)=180-BJC, and its easy to prove that BJC=2BAC, so ZSY+ZXY=180 (done)


1/ Are you saying that PCA = BAC/2 would imply that BCOP is concylic? If so, please add in the details to show your work. $\quad$ 2/ I would encourage you to post the original problem too.

@CalvinLin if we have PCA=BAC/2. we need OPC=OBC=90-BAC. we have OPC=180-POC-PCO, OCP=PCA-OCA and It is quite easy to calculate OPC through 3 angles A,B,C by extending CO to cut AM

@CalvinLin i have edit and add the original problem too, pls help =d


$\underline{\text{Lemma:}}$
As shown in $\mathrm{Fig.\space 1}$, scalene triangle $ABC$ is inscribed in the circle $\Omega$, center of which is located at $O$. If $H$ is the orthocenter of $\triangle ABC$, the distance between the vertex $A$ and $H$ is independent of the position of $A$ on the circumference of $\Omega$.
$\underline{\text{Proof of Lemma:}}$
To prove this lemma, we have enhanced the given diagram by locating the point $F$, which is the antipodal point of the vertex $C$. Then we draw the three auxiliary lines to joining $F$ to the three vertices of $\triangle ABC$. For brevity, we let $BC=a$ and the diameter of the circle $CF=2R$.
Since the angle in a semicircle is a right angle, the two triangles, i.e., $\triangle FBC$ and $\triangle CAF$, which are produced by the construction of auxiliary lines are right-angled triangles. With this, we have $\measuredangle FBS = \measuredangle CAF = 90^o$. Hence, the line segments $FB$ and $FA$ are parallel to the $A$-altitude and $B$-altitude of $\triangle ABC$ respectively. In other words, the opposite sides of the quadrilateral $ADBH$ are parallel. This makes $ADBH$ a parallelogram. Therefore, we shall write,
$$AH=FB. \tag{1}$$
Now, to express $FB$ in terms of $a$ and $R$, we apply Pythagoras theorem to $\triangle FBC$.
$$FB=\sqrt{4R^2-a^2}.\tag{2}$$
Using (1) and (2), we can deduce that,
$$AH=\sqrt{4R^2-a^2}.$$
So, the length of $AH$ depends only on two constants, i.e., radius $R$ of $\Omega$ and length $a$ of side $BC$.

$\underline{\text{Proof of Cyclicity of the Quadrilateral } BCOP} $
As shown in $\mathrm{Fig.\space 2}$, the given triangle is $ABC$ and its circumcircle is $\Omega$. Points $O$, $H$, $M$, and $P$ are taken as described in OP’s problem statement.
We draw two auxiliary line segments $OB$ and $OC$ to produce an isosceles triangle $BCO$. Next, we construct the circumcircle $\Gamma$ of $\triangle BCO$. Its center is located at $O_1$. The line segment $MO$ is extended to intersect $BC$, $\Omega$, and $\Gamma$, at $X$, $N$, and $K$ respectively. Finally, we draw a line parallel to $AM$ thorough $H$, so that it meets extended $MO$ at $J$.
For brevity, let $MA=b$ and the radius of $\Gamma$, $OO_1=R_1$. Our attempt is to show that point $P$ lies on $\Gamma$ by first deriving expressions for lengths $R_1$, $MJ$, $HJ$, and $OP$ in terms of $R$, $a$, and $b$.
Applying Pythagoras theorem to the right angled tringle $OXC$, we obtain,
$$OX=\sqrt{R^2-\dfrac{a^2}{4}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{4R^2-a^2}}{2}.\tag{3}$$
Radius of $\Gamma$ can be calculated using a formula or applying Pythagoras theorem to the pair of right-angled tringles $OXC$ and $CXO_1$. For its brevity, we decided to use the formula. Substituting the value of $OX$ from (3), we can express $R_1$ in terms of $R$ and $a$.
$$R_1=\dfrac{a\times R\times R}{4\times OX \times \dfrac{a}{2}}=\dfrac{R^2}{\sqrt{4R^2-a^2}}\tag{4}$$
Since $\space HJ \parallel AM\space$ and $\space MJ \parallel AH,\space$ according to the above-proven lemma, we have,
$$MJ=AH=\sqrt{4R^2-a^2}, \quad\text{and}\quad HJ=MA=b.\tag{5}$$
Now, after applying the theorem $\rm{\space Euclid\enspace VI.2\space}$ to $\triangle HJM$ and the intercepting line $PO$ parallel to $HJ$, we use (5) to obtain,
$$\dfrac{PO}{HJ}=\dfrac{MO}{MJ} \qquad\longrightarrow\qquad PO=\dfrac{bR}{\sqrt{4R^2-a^2}}.\tag{6}$$
Finally we compare the known sides and angles of the pair of triangles $MAN$ and $OPK$. Since $\space AM \parallel PO,\space$ we shall write,
$$\measuredangle NMA = \measuredangle KOP. \tag{7}$$
In addition to this angle-equality, we can also use (4) and (6) to derive the following relationships between the sides about the mentioned angles.
$$\dfrac{AM}{PO}={\small{\dfrac{b}{\dfrac{bR}{\sqrt{4R^2-a^2}}}}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{4R^2-a^2}}{R} \quad\text{and}\quad \dfrac{MN}{OK}={\small{\dfrac{2R}{2R_1}}} ={\small{\dfrac{2R}{\dfrac{2R^2}{\sqrt{4R^2-a^2}}}}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{4R^2-a^2}}{R}$$
$${\large{\bf{\therefore}}}\quad \dfrac{AM}{PO}=\dfrac{MN}{OK}.\tag{8}$$
According to the theorem $\rm{\space Euclid\enspace VI.6,\space}$ conditions (7) and (8) are necessary and sufficient for the triangles $MAN$ and $OPK$ to be equiangular. Hence, we have,
$$\measuredangle OPK = \measuredangle MAN =90^o,$$
which means that $\measuredangle OPK$ is an angle in a semicircle. In other words, $P$ lies on the circumference of the circle $COB$.

thánks you  so much

Happy to help you.
